# XSS in EUC-jp over htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

does a japanese charset euc-jp make a xss?

```
<html> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var a ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['a']) ?>";
    var b ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['b']) ?>";
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I would take get parameter a as %f0 then:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var a =";
    var b ="";
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I have The bad feeling from that

I'm glad that you give me a some examples

Answer (score 0):

You are pasting user input into Javascript directly. That is a XSS-injection field day. Japanese charset has nothing at all to do with it. Anyone could input any Javascript they like, and your code does nothing to stop it.

It is because you are encoding it against HTML character/escapes... not Javascript ones.

Comment: nn.. but why a quote is removed? a = "